# How to use a custom OLE dll in a java eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, dll, swt, eclipse-rcp, ole

I'm trying to use a custom OLE dll with a control in my Eclipse RCP Plugin.

The dll is in my working directory, but if I try to use it I get a SWTException:

I use this code:

```
Display display = Display.getCurrent();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
OleFrame frame = new OleFrame(shell, SWT.NONE);
OleClientSite site = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "MyCustomDll.TestControl");
OleAutomation test = new OleAutomation(site);
shell.open();
```

And get this Exception:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Class ID not found in registry
  at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE.error(OLE.java:317)
  at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE.error(OLE.java:283)
  at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleClientSite.<init>(OleClientSite.java:226)
  ...
```

How can I tell my plugin where to look for the Class ID?
There must be some basic point I'm missing but I didn't find anything about using custom OLE dlls.

Comment: I think you have to specify the full path of the file. Is TestControl a file type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of try and error I found the solution for my Problem:

My Dll was registered with:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\regasm
```

Instead I registered it with:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm
```

and it worked. I don't know why there are different versions anyway.

Comment: How can I registered to \Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm